# [Moveit!] 3D navigation for robot without arm

Tags: moveit

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I know Moveit! is the most used for robot with arms or quadrotors. My robot has no arm and only can move by wheels. It can navigate by 2D navigation stack(costmap_2d) now. Maybe my robot will has arms in the future, therefore I want to use 3D navigation stack(Moveit!). Can I use Moveit! to do 3D navigation even the robot without arm?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/259399/%5Bmoveit!%5D-3d-navigation-for-robot-without-arm/) by [simon.xm.lee](https://answers.ros.org/users/29522/simon.xm.lee/) on ROS Answers with karma: 43 on 2017-04-17

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Humpelstilzchen](https://answers.ros.org/users/21851/humpelstilzchen/) on 2017-04-18**:
Whats the problem with navigating your robot in 2d e.g. from the table do the fridge and do only the short range arm operations in 3d?

**Comment by [simon.xm.lee](https://answers.ros.org/users/29522/simon.xm.lee/) on 2017-04-18**:
I just survey the feasibility by using the 2D navigation with Moveit!. My robot has no arm.

**Comment by [simon.xm.lee](https://answers.ros.org/users/29522/simon.xm.lee/) on 2017-04-18**:
BTW, my robot is differential drive robot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Now I just survey the feasibility by using the 2D navigation with Moveit!, because my robot has no arm. I just want to know whether moveit! can do 2D navigation as costmap_2d.

I find someone said that the Moveit! cannot do 2D navigation now and developer should write the navigation planner for 2D navigation. Therefore I start to doubt the 2D navigation function of Moveit!.  In addition, I find lots of moveit! tutorials and simulation videos only present the arm motion planning but no 2D path planning.

---

Originally posted by [simon.xm.lee](https://answers.ros.org/users/29522/simon.xm.lee/) with karma: 43 on 2017-04-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0